# Workflow for animation idle, walk cycling , jump?

Tags: animation

Hi I would like to know if I should create differents animation in the same scene or in differents files ? my target is export my 3d character to unity , and create animation in blender , as walking, jump, death, attack, stand area, etc .

I started with Idle animation in 48 frames. the clip end at 47 and loop to keyframe 1. ... but then I do not know If I should create another different animation from keyframe 48 or simply go to reset all the transformation or scene?

[image]

Comment: If you were working with blender game engine you could add a new action to the skeleton inside the dopesheet panel, this will make your timeline virgin for a new animation, then you pick up each action independently with game logic bricks. If you need your animation bind to the exported model then you should indeed have all of your character's animations on the timeline I guess.

Comment: hi, not I prefer to export to unity or unreal , I know something about c++ and c# , but I need to create things in unity for example to call the differents animations I ve created.

Comment: I have no clues about how unity works, at all.. It's just a mater of mastering your API, if you need to learn C programming languages though i recommend working on linux, It makes code writting/compiling really intuitive, though you won't have access to unreal engine or others I think source 2 engine and unity will be/is compatible.
Anyway from the blender manual about the export format-
"Use FBX: if you intend to export objects with rigs and/or animation to be used in other 3D creation suites or game development."

Comment: yes I know something about programming , perphaps I am going to creat action for every animation.